# Outputting salt-mine data into template

Tags: saltstack

Can anyone spot my error here. I have the following in the minion config:

```
mine_functions:
  network.interfaces: []
```

I expect the following to return the IP of all minions:

```
{% for ip in salt['mine.get']('*', 'network.interfaces', ['eth0']).items() %}
{{ ip }}
{% endfor %}
```

The state fails with the following:

> Unable to manage file: Jinja error: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'.

I've also tried doing it another way:

```
{% set hosts = salt['mine.get']('*', 'network.interfaces') %}
{% for i in hosts %}
{{ hosts[i]['eth0']['inet'][0]['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

From this I get:

> variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'inet';

If I remove `inet`, `0` and `address` it works but outputs all interface info when I only want the `IP` of `eth0`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

# use network.ip_addrs instead

```
mine_functions:
  network.ip_addrs: [eth0]
```